# How to config the `no-cycle` rule in eslint-plugin-import for typescript?

Tags: typescript, eslint

There are three `.ts` files, `a.ts` and `b.ts` are circular imported each other, while `c.ts` imports both `a.ts` and `b.ts`.

When checking `c.ts`, I expect that ESLint reports the circular depencency.

But for some reason, running `yarn eslint src/c.ts` does NOT raise any error !!!

`a.ts`:

```
import y from "./b";

const x: number = y + 1;
export default x;
```

`b.ts`:

```
import x from "./a";

const y: number = x + 1;
export default y;
```

`c.ts`:

```
import x from "./a";
import y from "./b";

console.log(x, y);
```

and the `.eslintrc.json`:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/warnings",
    "plugin:import/typescript"
  ],
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint", "import"],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "project": "./tsconfig.json"
  },
  "settings": {
    "import/extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
    "import/parsers": {
      "@typescript-eslint/parser": [".ts", ".tsx"]
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "import/no-cycle": [
      "error",
      {
        "maxDepth": 10,
        "ignoreExternal": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The github repo:  https://github.com/Yaojian/no-cycle-test

Comment: https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/issues/2895

Answer (score 1):

It won't raise the lint error in `c.ts` file because the circular dependency is between `a.ts` and `b.ts`. [ESLint no-cycle rule description.](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-cycle.md#importno-cycle)

`a.ts file`
[image]

`b.ts file`
[image]

Comment: I think the `maxDepth` option means to check the imported modules from `c.ts`?